# event.preventDefault() vs. return false vs Event.stopPropagation() and other methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, onsubmit

I am using a form and on submit
 `$(document).on('submit','form',function(event){`

now I want to stop the form from being submitted to validate. The options I found are

```
event.preventDefault()
Event.stopPropagation()
return false
throw new Error("Something went badly wrong!");
calling a fake function which does not exist
```

Would anyone explain which one I should use and are there more methods to stop the execution of Javascript form submission?

Comment: use `return false;` if form is not valid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rundown:

- You can use [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) if you **only** want to prevent the default of the event (in this case, submitting a form).
- You can use [`return false`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (in a jQuery event handler like yours) if you want to **both** prevent the default and stop propagation of the event to ancestor elements. (Note that that's different from what `return false` means in native event handling, as I cover in [this blog post](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/11/story-on-return-false.html).)
- Using [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) (not `Event.stopPropagation()`) **won't** prevent the default action at all: the form will still be submitted.
- Throwing an error from the handler **won't** prevent the default action of the event.
- Calling a function that doesn't exist is just throwing an error, see above.